# How to convert following query in rails 3 active record query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to find last 20 days latest data from audit table for that I have written following MySQL query:

```
 SELECT * 
 from   (select * from audits ORDER BY id DESC) as x 
 where  (auditable_type = 'Investment' 
 and    auditable_id =41 
 and    created_at <= '2011-12-01' AND  created_at >= '2011-11-25')  
 group by date(created_at)
```

I want to convert it to rails 3 active record query, how should I do so I will get same result from both the queries?

Comment: Why do you need this sub-query in the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get much better than that (without using some gems like [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where)):

```
Audits.where(
    'DATE(created_at) <= ? AND DATE(created_at) >= ? 
     AND auditable_type = ? AND auditable_id = ?',
    Date.new(2011, 12, 01), Date.new(2011, 11, 25), 'Investement', 41
).group('DATE(created_at)').order('id DESC')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding but it will not returning  anything and if i do .to_sql on this query it will not returning the sql query which i have mentioned above

Comment: I want to find data from that date range but latest updated. means say there are 3 record for date 20 so my query should return latest updated record for date 20

Comment: Well, your query contains sub-query that I still don't understand. And as it doesn't have limit clause it should return all records that satisfy conditions and not only latest by update time, shouldn't it?